# Ensuring correctness property in multi-party protocols

Tags: multiparty-computation, adversarial-model

Can you suggest mechanisms to ensure the correctness of the protocol output, against Active Adversaries in multi-party protocols. Specifically for a dishonest majority setting?

I would like to have paper references that would allow me to continue my research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correctness is a property of the protocol. For Semi-Honest Adversaries comes out of the box (it is the goal of the protocol to be correct). If you are talking about adversarial models then maybe:

Is it your real question maybe how to be secure against Active Adversaries, (Parties are allowed to manipulate the protocol)?

In that case: The SPDZ family could be a good modern option for your question. They are dishonest majorities protocols, that offer cryptographic security with abort (so correctness):

This is the [original SPDZ](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/535.pdf) protocol. A more advance version of it (and the more efficient at the moment) is [SPDZ Overdrive](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1230.pdf).

Such protocols have been implemented, more notably in the [SCALE-MAMBA Library](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~nsmart/SCALE/).

I assume you are considering other options as well, maybe more questions come to mind such as: Do you represent your functions as Arithmetic Vs. Boolean Circuits. Would you prefer something strong than the abort security? Are there optimized versions for Honest Majorities? Etc.

For these questions I would suggest you to give a look to this [awesome list](https://github.com/rdragos/awesome-mpc) that is mantained by the community.